# Having trouble accessing an argument of a function in jquery get

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get

I am attempting to access the value echoed by my php file using jquery. I am running this on an apache server. My code is

My PHP (findjson.php) file is:

```
<?php
    foreach (glob("*.json") as $filename)
        echo $filename;
?>
```

Part of my Javascript/html file

```
...
<script id='code-js' type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("findjson.php", function(data) {
        alert(data); //uncomment this for debug
        $('#showdata').html(data);
    }, 'text');
});
...

function load(){

    var docname = $('#showdata');

    Scene.loadObject(docname);
}
```

I would like docname in the function load to be set to data. I am unsure on how to proceed though, have tried a variety of ways, and am out of ideas. I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-get.htm . I tried using global variables, but for some reason, global variables don't seem to work well in the function(data) (I assume because it is a call back function). I also tried using a this.data = data line in the function but that didn't seem to work very well either.

Comment: Its asynchronus, so you need to call load() after `$('#showdata').html(data);`  Why can't you just call `Scene.loadObject` from the $.get function ?

Comment: Just put `Scene.loadObject(data)` in the success callback and forget about `load`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("findjson.php", function(data) {
        alert(data); //uncomment this for debug
        Scene.loadObject(data);
        //or you could do
        $('#showdata').data('scenedata', data);
    }, 'text');
});

function load(){
   var docname = $('#showdata').data("scenedata")
   Scene.loadObject(docname);
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response - It does make sense, but I was wondering, is there perhaps a way to access that argument outside of the $.get in the case that I need it later on?

Comment: You can, use .data see above.